# Why did god create violence?

Tags: ahimsa

Violence is something always in nature.Animals killing each other. God created carnivores.Who will make carnivores understand that ahimsa is important . If god wanted god could just have created peace loving people.Then why didnt god?

Comment: Everything has been created. Goodness and Badness are not absolute. Absolute truth doesn't have any such duality or limitations

Comment: All duality of life is an illusion. You are not your body, you are not your mind, you are not your motions, you are this cosmos in yourself.

Answer (score 0):

God hasn't created violence on purpose

It is Prakriti or Maayaa made up of the three guNas that has become transformed as all the bodies, (which is the multiplicity of its individual proportion of gunas).
Maya is beginningless, so when it first came into existence ?, why different jivas (species) has different gunas? is inexplicable (anirvachaniya) ,so cannot be known.Also the creation of God is cyclic in nature.God does not suddenly create a vilolent animal out of nothing . It is already unmanifest in Prakrithi and so it manifests during creation.

> Maayaa is called Unmanifest. It is the power of Parameshvara, the supreme Lord. It is beginningless Nescience. It is constituted of the three guNas, sattva, rajas and tamas. Its existence cannot be directly known, but can only be inferred from its effects. It is the cause of this universe.
>  Vivekachudamani verse 110( Translation Sri SN Saastri)

Bhagavad Gita 8.19 (Akshara Brahma yog) -

> भूतग्राम: स एवायं भूत्वा भूत्वा प्रलीयते |
> रात्र्यागमेऽवश: पार्थ प्रभवत्यहरागमे || 
> Multitudes of beings repeatedly take      birth with the advent of Brahma’s day,    and are reabsorbed on the arrival of        the cosmic night, to manifest again        automatically on the advent of the
> next cosmic day.
> (Swami Mukundananda)

Bhagavad Gita 9.7,8 (Rajavidya yog)

> सर्वभूतानि कौन्तेय प्रकृतिं यान्ति मामिकाम् |
> कल्पक्षये पुनस्तानि कल्पादौ विसृजाम्यहम् ||
> प्रकृतिं स्वामवष्टभ्य विसृजामि पुन: पुन: |
> भूतग्राममिमं कृत्स्नमवशं प्रकृतेर्वशात् || 
> At the end of one kalp, all living beings merge into My primordial material energy. At the beginning of the next creation, O son of Kunti, I manifest them again. Presiding over My material energy, I generate these myriad forms again and again, **in accordance with the force of their natures.**
> (Swami Mukundananda)

> Mahā Pralaya: At the end of Brahma’s life, this entire universe goes into dissolution. Again, all the souls of the universe unmanifest and stay in the body of Maha Vishnu(Brahman). Their gross (sthūl) and subtle (sūkṣhma) body dissolve, but their causal body (kāraṇ sharīr) stays. In the next cycle of creation, these souls are reborn based on their past karmas and past sanskārs, which the soul’s causal body stores and carries with it.
> (Swami Mukundananda)

Srimad Bhagavad Puran 4.9.16

> yasmin viruddha-gatayo hy aniśaṁ
> patanti..
> In whose creation
> opposite/contradictory character
> always manifest...

Comment: why doesn't god take away violence now?@Athrey

Comment: @Shiv , In the age of Kali there is a natural expectancy  of violence and unrighteous, God has  already  protected mankind  thru His  teaching and it's spiritual purport of Bhagavad Gita.There might be several incarnations of God to protect the moral order.Its upto the particular individual to choose the right path and forbid/ignore adharmic ways.Despondency over unrighteousness and violence is a sign of weakness. There are several examples in history , who stood by dharma on difficult situations. (For.eg Jija Mata, Sri Bhagat Singh , list would go on unabated..)

Answer (score 0):

CREATION:

Understanding creation is not easy and cant be done in a janma. That's how the " SECRETS of CREATION are not revealed to humans in Kali Yuga".

```
   GOD's CREATIONS on Earth
```

Aaranya, Nara, Naari, Graama, Pashubhihi (tamed animals), Sthaavarani, Varaprasatham (Nectars of further creation), Rituparnaani (seasons) for waters & beings.

CREATIONS modified by SPIRITS that failed to attain UPPER SAMASTA LOKHA
(" MAMO PARTHA SAMASTHA DURITHA KSHAYA DWARA .......slokam is there)

Earth is not near GOD's abode. But GOOD AASHRAMA humans (Sanaatanis) inherited GOD in them to make Earth safe place for humans.
GOD's abode is LIGHT YEARS distant from from Earth.

Example: the number of days in a year is different for different planets. But, Earth is a place where all humans/ beings have definite form.

Sinners who had enjoyed Earth without considering beings on Earth inherited bad spirits that were driven away far from GOD's abode & Earth. Since the sinners had inherited bad spirits the animals humans and beings got mutated by different characteristics that relied "Survival as just Suppressor". This is how carnivores genetically formed. Humans with bad spirits were better than carnivores but were addictive to unending sex and abuse on females. This produced bad humans of DEMONAIC traits (resemblingvasuras but only fractionally) & DEMONAIC animals (Daanavasur (dinosur) ) , Paathala Sarpa (Anaconda) and venomous beings due to blood mutations.

Thus GOD never created bad on Earth. Its human nad spirits of DEMONAIC that ended in Kali Yuga.

```
       POSSIBLE SOLUTION
```

If more humans collectively pray GOD with minimum needs on other beings this KaliYuga will change into Dwapara Yuga where
Humans could even fly distant with Eagles , travel 10000 km long with Zebralions without fuels etc.