# Is this world a garbage?

Tags: gods

In everyone's house, there is a place where we bin our wastes, we dont often go to that place, out of 24hrs we have, we spend around 10mins a day in that place(max), If we want something from that bin, we sometimes go and search for it and bring it back,we even forget the existence of such place unless there are some leftovers in our place, for some reason, if that place is affected by some worms or started smelling super bad, we go there and make some real effort and clean that place and then bring it back to its own original form. i.e being a waste collector.

Similarly, bhagavan has its own house and his garbage is this earth, where he throws the wastes i.e everything that exists here, he does not care anything about here, similar to us spending 10 mins in those places, he hardly spend time here, if the basket is full of filth(adharma, according to him), he spends more time here(avatar) and clean it up and restore the garbage state of it and then he goes back to its own house and does not stay here.

We human beings, thinking the garbage area of Lord to be our home , because lord thrown us here, is this one of the right ways of seeing the current state of affairs in this earth?

Comment: Person who downvoted, either did not read properly the scriptures or does not understand the question.

Comment: well.. samsara is defined as dukha-sagar (ocean of misery) compared to vaikunta, so in a sense, yes.. the world is garbage and we need to get out of here after getting freedom (moksha)

Comment: why someone put us here and then asking us to get out of here?

Comment: @religiousquestion ,   God has not  created miseries on purpose.It is part of Prakrithi , which is beginningless. (according to scriptures)., Yet God is the only one who can redeem us from all the trouble.thereby a firm faith on God always helps, Earth is place conducive for a Jiva to evolve, progress.despite of all downsides.
This could be to some extent related to the question.(in the light of scriptures)
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53056/why-did-god-create-violence

Comment: See this from another perspective, out of trillions of organisms God chose your birth specifically to be that of a human, the best of opportunities one can ever get on earth.Second blessing was he invoked vairagya in you at a young age that this world is just an illusion with all its material pleasures false,"Brahm Satya Jagan Mithya"
You are really fortunate unlike others who are wasting their lives deeply enjoying material pleasures.

Comment: Every soul is potentially divine and the goal of this life is to realize the divinity of your soul ~Swami Vivekananda
Even God wishes that you break free from this cycle of samsara and ultimately become one with him.
Earth isnt a garbage land but a battlefield,where your at war with the 6 enemies of your mind viz. kama (desire), krodha (anger), lobha (greed), Mada (arrogance), moha (delusion), and matsarya (jealousy).

Comment: @Athrey if god has not created miseries on purpose, who did it? From his ears came mathu and kaitab, the template of beasts, his security people has become hiranyaksh/hiranykasibu, sisupal/thandhavakra, ravan/kumbakarn, so he is the sole reason of all these beasts

Comment: @Rāmachandra There is nothing called "Every soul", the deepest requirement in spirituality is removing that I, but how you are telling "Every soul" is beyond my imagination, to let us know that consistently, people like vivekananda,prabhupada,adishankaracharya,ramakrishna are being taken away from us, i hope you understand this.

Comment: *"why someone put us here"* - who said *someone* put you here ? maybe you came here because you wanted to. and you can leave anytime you want.

Comment: @religious question Dear fellow stack exchange member i am unable to understand your doubt.If you  are trying to claim there exists no concept like Soul(Atman)/Conciousness then you tou are basically rejecting the whole of Hindu Philosophy.Also, You are right one of the goal of spirituality is to remove the "I" which in itself means destroying ones ego(Mada),destroying "I" means realising you are neither the mind nor the body you are the untainted pure omnipresent omnipotent Brahman.I would advise you to read SV's Complete works sections on Raja Yoga  and Jnana Yoga for a better understanding.

Comment: @Rāmachandra Soul is present, there is no denial of that, what i meant was, there is no individual identity for anyone, be it anyone, Be it vivekananda or ramakrishna or adi sankaracharya or ramanuja or prabhupada.

Comment: @mar without someone putting us here, we would have never known this place, how do you know that we wanted to come here and that is why we are here.

Comment: I am sensing from your questions that you havent read much of Hindu philosophy  **yet** .You are asking a layered question that cannot be explained in the comments.Instead edit your question restricting it to one or two Qns so that we can try giving you precise answers.What you are asking is why was i ever born /am i just a toy for God/Why does God treat us like garbage/Why does he not care for us etc.Also humble advice would be to not post random stuff that you just made up and now you want answers for them.Atleast put some effort into searching for its answers,mention your research.

Comment: Read some basic texts on Hinduism,tell us what you have read,so we can give you specific advice,show that you have atleast made an effort to find an answers.

Comment: I am really sorry if i offended you but i meant no disrespect, I just wanted you to ask specific questions.

Comment: @Rāmachandra well it is typical of people telling me similar things when they lack answers, as you said, i have layer of questions, because one answer leads to another question and people should be ready to answer in whatever forms it is asked, the problem is many people are book worms and they are not ready to adapt themselves to a question being asked, they just want others to listen to their recitation. I am not offended at all, as i am open to whatever being discussed. Will ask layer by layer as people are struggling to understand deeper things.

Comment: Sir its not that ppl are struggling but its just that your way of asking is not organized.Your thought process is scattered.U are unable to condense all of our questions.There are many users like Swami Vishwananda,Rickross and all our site moderators who could provide you very deep,insightful and beautiful answers here,only if you ask politely and your question seems worth reading(Pls edit your question it seems really messy)No we are not here to solve your doubts but to help /give you a nudge so that u can figure it out yourself.Consider us as fellow seekers in search of the Absolute Truth!

Comment: *"how do you know that we wanted to come here and that is why we are here."* - how do you know that someone put us here ? anyway the answer to your question is in Brahma Sutras - Bhagavan does not play partiality, nor impose any rule that you HAVE to play in samsara.

Answer (score 2):

you're right this world is a garbage the only reason we've come here it to suffer at least most of us come here to suffer may be it gives them(gods) pleasure to see us suffering all thoose who are saying God sent us for this God sent us for that are just lying some people just born as God's favourite but you and me are not one of em  we are just born to suffer you've heard about krishna right he was just born special born with great looks,great charm,great strength,great skills it's like he was just born to be greatest we are not like him were trash born with no skills,strength,looks or charm you can say that it's bcz of our past karma but then again we don't have free will according to scriptures so it can't be our karma right now we're living in kaliyuga rhe age of adharma duryodhna molested daruoadi that was adharma but thousands of girls getting raped everyday that's not adharma According to our God right he's waiting for end of kaliyuga so that when sins are at its peak he will come and kill almost everyone of us and gets called hero again the savior of fucking dharma the only thing I'm trying to say is our gods favorite hobby is to watch us suffer you get it.... accptvit or not you're too weak to do anything the only thing you can do is suffer

Comment: I think is normal to feel like this, tough situations, lotsa days I feel bewildered & kinda lost too. Life is difficult for everyone, right ? Why so many rich successful ppl are alcoholic, drugs addict, substance abuse issues, on anti depressants, or even commit suicide  But I think we could work hard try fix things & improve stuff. I don’t think world is garbage, just things are really hard sometimes. Hang in there & feel better  (I changed my name from “devibhakt” coz getting more vegan environmentalist & cause worried that name was bhakti ka dhikawa, which isn’t good. But is still me.)

Comment: @veganenvironmentalist oh thnks bro just wrote this comment when I was in a very bad mood

Comment: @AbhinavRaj There should be a larger understanding than this. I did not say these because of sufferings that we face everyday, it is a different point altogether.

Answer (score 0):

*Commented in reply here ,as the comment  space is insufficient*

Creation,sustenance and dissolution of the universe occur in continuous cycles.

One can't say all these ,started at some point in time wherein God created the whole cosmos out of nothing, unlike some other non-dharmic philosophy.

Multitude of jivas,  rests latent in stomach of God (Vishnu) during yoga-nidra during dissolution which includes both sinner and the saint.

God during creation, by His sankalpa Shakti, manifests all the jivas back, that were latent in His stomach upon previous disssolution.

Here Jiva is born out of its past karma. Karma and Janma is beginningless , as in the case of seed and tree ..

Madhu and Kaitaba emerge out of  mala(dirt) from Lords ears upon creation..(here ear signifies shabda,and hence creation)   They are the embodiment of rajas and tamas(as in scriptures). which means controdictory aspects  ( bad as well along with good) manifests during creation. (Although God can subdue the evil  that has manifested)

**Jaya and Vijaya**

> The obstruction caused by Jaya and Vijaya at the last rampart represents the last traces of raga (attachment) and dvesha (aversion)..Just as the sages(Sankadhi rishis) pushed away Jaya and Vijaya from their path, (having successfully crossed other six ramparts) the aspirant should push out even the last traces of attachment and aversion from his mind and make his mind pure.It is significant that as soon as the sages pushed away Jaya and Vijaya by a curse, the Lord appeared before them. This indicates that, once the aspirant has become completely free from attachment and aversion, Self-realization will dawn immediately.
>
>  SN Saastri

Hence Jaya and Vijaya upon manifestation , manifest as asuras, finally subdued by Lord.

Other references -Bhagavad Gita 8.19 ,
9.7,8